# Jquery autocomplete: How to ignore comma as delimiter

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am currently having some trouble with the autocomplete widget from Jquery. I have a remote datasource where some of the strings (or search terms) have commas in them. As soon as I type a comma in the input text box, the list of suggestions disappear.

To me it seems that the autocomplete widget uses comma as a delimiter. How can I easily ignore the comma so I can display the right result?

Here is my code:

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            that._renderItemData( ul, item );
        });
    }
});


$(".sottendeDokumenterSearchField").catcomplete({
    source: "myURL",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        return processAutocompleteElSelected(event, ui);
    },
    open: function(event, ui){
        if(autoselect){
            var keyEvent = $.Event("keydown");          
            keyEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.DOWN;

            $(".sottendeDokumenterSearchField").trigger(keyEvent); 
            keyEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER; 
            $(".sottendeDokumenterSearchField").trigger(keyEvent); 
        }

        autoselect = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try going into the jquery.autocomplete.ui JS file, and finding and removing the comma case from that code. Then the field would never look for it. I'm not sure which version of ui or which build you are using.

Comment: Aye, I could do that, but would rather not. Problem with that is that if/when I upgrade to a new version of jquery ui, then I have to fix it again. It is easy to forget.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the input value to your autocomplete function, strip it from comma's with a str_replace.

I'm not familiar with the autocomplete widget so I can't give any code examples, sorry. Hope it can still point you to the right direction though.

Comment: That will not work, because the search term will not match the source. I could strip comma from both source and search term, but that is an inferior solution. Would rather then do what user-a5567lfg suggests.